# For template classes, do non generic member functions get duplicated?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Or only the ones that actually use generic parts?

Like in this example:

```
template<class T>
class foo
{
public:
    void addStuff(int x,T y)
    {

        ints_.push_back(x);
        generics_.push_back(y);
    }
    void clear() 
    {
        ints_.clear();
        generics_.clear();
    }
    void setName(std::string name)
    {

        name_ = name;
    }

    std::string name_;

    std::vector<int> ints_;
    std::vector<T> generics_;
};
```

The non generic functions are inline, since putting them in a .cpp file would require specialization.
Doe they get duplicated as well?
Just curious...

Answer (score 4):

Each class which is created via a template parameter is its own class.  That is, if you had `foo<int>`, `foo<double>` and `foo<char>` then there would exist 3 different addStuff, clear and setName functions.  That's because there would be 3 different classes.  Templates are compile time entities.  They are introduced during compilation and there is no attempt at "reducing" code size like this.

Comment: You could always create a non-template base class, if you really wanted to.  Not much point for setName, but maybe more useful for other situations:  `class HasName { public:  void setName(const std::string& name) { name_ = name; }  std::string name_; };  template<class T> class foo : public HasName ...`

Answer (score 3):

Technically, yes, since they are distinct functions belonging to distinct classes.  In practice, maybe, since compilers/linkers are pretty smart and have figured out that such repeated code can be condensed in many situations.  And there is always the possibility that they are not inlined completely such that no actual function needs to be stored at all.

There is a definite cost in executable size for using template trickery, but it is not as much now as it was in years past.